# Can a viewcontroller transform one if its views when keyboard is brought up in another viewcontroller

Tags: swift, swift3

So I have a view controller with an IBOutlet pointing to a view that has an embedded navigation controller which leads to another viewcontroller which is where I am brining up the keyboard I know these handlers exist but is there any way to transform the view that this controller is embedded in?

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification){
    // Do something here
    print("shown")
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification){
    // Do something here
    print("notshown")
}
```

Comment: Have the view controller you want to transform listen for the notifications.  If it is initialized and in the view hierarchy, it will receive the notification and you can do whatever you need from it.

Comment: @JAL I tried this but thanks for suggesting maybe I did it wrong so ill attempt this again